# Adding tool tips to Add-In Menu in Enterprise Architect through API

Tags: menu, tooltip, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect with C# Add-Ins. I am trying to check the Add-In menu item and also add tool tip to display information about that feature.

I tried the following code :

```
public void EA_GetMenuState(EA.Repository Repository, string Location, string MenuName, string ItemName, ref bool IsEnabled, ref bool IsChecked)
    {
        //Enables the menu if the project is open
        if (IsProjectOpen(Repository))
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            if (ItemName.Equals("Help"))
            {
               //check the menu
                IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
```

The menu item check works fine but unable to find an option to add tool tip to the menu.

I referred this link:
 https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=4129.0 where a feature request for tool tips is mentioned.

Is is possible to set menu tool tip through Add-in in EA Version 12.1?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

You can send in your own [feature request](https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html) in order to add weight to the request.